# how to show v-for from two different aray from data() vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<ul class="chart-box__info-chartlist">
   <li v-for="item in datachart.labels">
       <i class="chart-icon chart-icon_1"></i>
       <span>{{ item.label }} - {{ item.color }}</span> 
   </li>
</ul>  

data() {
            return {
                cb_info_sm: this.links[0].cb_info_sm,
                cb_info_sm_color: this.links[0].cb_info_sm_color,
                cb_info_label: this.links[0].cb_info_label,
                cb_info_url: this.links[0].cb_info_url,
                activeclass: 0,
                datachart: {
                    labels: this.links[0].data_lables.map( item => item.title),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Chart',
                        backgroundColor: this.links[0].data_lables.map( item => item.color),
                        data: this.links[0].data_lables.map( item => item.value),
                        borderColor: '#ffffff'
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
```

Data is changing dynammicaly, and i need to show two values color from datachart.datasets[0].backgroundColor and label from datachart.labels , maybe someone know, how to do this with v-for?

Comment: Are labels in `labels` somehow linked to stuff in `datasets`? What I mean is that you have a `label` in your object in `datasets`, why not display just that one?

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is dirty and I recommend to restructure and clean your datachart object, but if you insisting on keeping this object, then you can define a computed property and make a v-for on that:

```
computed : {
  newDataChart () {
    return this.datachart.labels.map(item => {label: item, color: this.datachart.datasets[0].backgroundColor})
  }
}
```